# CSS Background Image - 100% width until a threshold is met

Tags: html, css

I've seen on a few websites in the past where a background image on a big DIV (say 100vh and 100vw) will stretch as the browser grows, but when a certain lower threshold is met (e.g. 800px), the background image doesn't stay at 100%, but starts clipping the background image instead.

I can't find those pages anymore now that I need to do it myself.  CSS solution?

Comment: Use css media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `100vh` and `100vw` something like below -

```css
body {
  margin:0; /* reset any browser-default margins */
  height:100vh; 
  width:100vw; 
}

img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" />
</body>
```

Hope this will help you in some way (y).